# Custom File Explorer for huge set of files (winform c#)

Tags: c#, winforms

What windows form controls should best serve to display huge number of files (10 million). Displaying thumbnails for such huge number of files bothers for memory constraint as displaying 10 million thumbnails would consume too much memory. Quick search for TreeView and ListView suggests that they have limitation for max items and nodes.

Wonder what Windows File Explorer uses for this. Any ideas ?

**(Thumbnails give a preview of content of files in case of images so using limited set of icons is not the option)**

Comment: Who would want to browse 10 million icons to find what he or she is looking for ?? Maybe you should rethink the solution.. is it possible to do some sort of grouping, custom filtering, etc..

Comment: See [Virtual Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use paging. There is no benefit in showing/loading millions of rows/thumbnails etc.
Also this will really hurt the UX.
Also i think you should add some search capability.
Look [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/211551/A-Simple-way-for-Paging-in-DataGridView-in-WinForm) for some paging solution.